# The minimum degree of interpolating polynomial that fits table data points.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, interpolation

What is the minimum degree that an interpolating polynomial that fits all five data points exactly can have? The following table data points are given for (x,f(x)):
(-0.5,5),(0,15),(0.5,9),(1,3),(1.5,1).
I'm not sure where to start. I think there is only one point where f'(x) = 0 but I'm not sure what it says about the degree though.

Comment: Start with a simpler problem. If you have two points, what is the minimum degree of the polynomial going through the two points? How about three points? Then you can conclude the result for five data points.

Comment: If I follow your logic: 2 points would require a degree of 1, while 3 points a degree of 2 and so forth. But isn't it possible that you can have a 30 points and still require only a polynomial of degree 1 permitted all the dots are on a straight line?

Comment: You are correct. But we're looking at the minimum degree that would fit ALL sets of 5 points (or 30 points) ... In some cases you do get lucky and some of the coefficients become zero.

Comment: Does this mean I can answer this answer without actually looking at the values of the data points? What do you mean if you get lucky? What is the significance of the coefficients becoming zero? I don't always understand the role of coefficients in a polynomial.

Comment: Well, in this case it turns out that you actually do need a 4th degree polynomial to fit all the points. (I calculated it quickly and the polynomial is $f(x) = -8x^4 + \frac{88}{3}x^3 - 30x^2 - \frac{10}{3}x+15$). For polynomials of degree 3 or higher, it can be difficult to "easily" see if the required degree is equal to $n-1$ or less. So I guess you just need to do the cold and hard computation.

Comment: Thank you. This question followed another that required I set up a difference table for the data points. I assume that from the difference table I can see whether any of the coefficients would be zero and from there determine the minimum degree.